# How to automate SSRS configuration

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, automation

This is my scenario: I have to setup a number of TFS 2013 Application Tier nodes (at least 6) and I am trying to automate the process, the nodes hosts also SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 SP1 in "cluster" (better group) configuration. I have no problem in installing SQL, but I am stuck with Reporting Services configuration.

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159720%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) states to use WMI to configure URLs, and the [MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154070%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) class has a SetVirtualDirectory which seems appropriate. I see that the value changes in RS Configuration Manager, but the message

> Report Server Web Service is not configured.

do not disappear.

My Powershell code is

```
$wmiName = (Get-WmiObject –namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer  –class __Namespace).Name
$rsConfig = Get-WmiObject –namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$wmiName\v11\Admin" -class MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting  -filter "InstanceName='SQLTFS'"

CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetVirtualDirectory("ReportServerWebService","ReportServer",0)
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetVirtualDirectory("ReportManager","Reports",0)
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetDatabaseConnection($DatabaseInstance, $DatabaseName, 2, $SqlCredential.UserName, $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
# force refresh
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetServiceState($false,$false,$false)
Restart-Service $rsConfig.ServiceName
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetServiceState($true,$true,$true)
# set key
& "$SQLBin\RSKeyMgmt.exe" -a -i SQLTFS -f $SSRSEncryptKeyFile -p $SSRSEncryptPassword
# join group
& "$SQLBin\RSKeyMgmt.exe" -j -m $workingNode -i SQLTFS -n SQLTFS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the culprit: need to call ReserveURL and use the `http://+:80` syntax for the URL. Calling this API restart the services so it could take a while to respond.

New version of script is

```
$wmiName = (Get-WmiObject –namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer  –class __Namespace).Name

$rsConfig = Get-WmiObject –namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$wmiName\v11\Admin" -class MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting -filter "InstanceName='SQLTFS'"
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetDatabaseConnection($DatabaseInstance, $DatabaseName, 2, $SqlCredential.UserName, $SqlCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)

CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetVirtualDirectory("ReportServerWebService","ReportServer",$lcid)
CheckHResult $rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportServerWebService","http://+:80",$lcid)
CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetVirtualDirectory("ReportManager","Reports",$lcid)
CheckHResult $rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportManager","http://+:80",$lcid)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
# set key
& "$SQLBin\RSKeyMgmt.exe" -a -i SQLTFS -f $SSRSEncryptKeyFile -p $SSRSEncryptPassword
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
# join group
& "$SQLBin\RSKeyMgmt.exe" -j -m $workingNode -i SQLTFS -n SQLTFS
Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

CheckHResult $rsConfig.SetServiceState($true,$true,$true)
```

Answer (score 3):

I work in a datacenter and prior to discovering this method, I used an autoit program to configure the SSRS instance.

The thing I would like to add to this solution is configuring SSL and it can be done as follows

```
$certhash = Get-ChildItem -path cert:\localmachine\my | Where {$_.subject -match <yourdomain> } | select -ExpandProperty thumbprint
$certhash = $certhash.tolower() #important
$sslPort = 443
$sslUrl = "https://+:443/"
$lcid = 1033 # for english


$rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportServerWebService", $sslUrl, $lcid)
$rsConfig.CreateSSLCertificateBinding("ReportServerWebService", $certHash, "0.0.0.0", $sslPort, $lcid)

$rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportManager", $sslUrl, $lcid)
$rsConfig.CreateSSLCertificateBinding("ReportManager", $certHash, "0.0.0.0", $sslPort, $lcid)

# Stop and Start SQL Server's Reporting Services to ensure changes take affect
$rsconfig.SetServiceState($false, $false, $false)
$rsconfig.SetServiceState($true, $true, $true)
```

Some other very useful resources are

> http://babercode.blogspot.com/2012/03/powershell-report-server-integration_21.html
>
> https://ruiromanoblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/configure-reporting-services-ssl-binding-with-wmi-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

So, I just found a PowerShell module to help with configuration via script. Under the covers, it uses WMI and is incomplete (no certificate methods), but it is much more concise than before.

The module, which is from Microsoft: [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools)

And Finally, if your setup requires SSL, the code below should help. It is inspired by [this post](https://community.certifytheweb.com/t/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/332).

```
$instanceName =  "SSRS"
$sqlVersionNumber = "13"
$httpsPort = 443;
$ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";
$certNameMath = "name of the certificate";

$rsConfig = Get-WmiObject –namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_$instanceName\v$sqlVersionNumber\Admin" -class MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting -filter "InstanceName='$instanceName'"

$existingHttps = $rsConfig.ListReservedUrls().UrlString | Where {$_ -eq "https://+:$httpsPort"}
if( ($existingHttps | Measure).Count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "no https, setting up"
    $result = $rsConfig.ListSSLCertificates();
    $certHash = ""

    for($i = 0; $i -lt ($result.CertName|Measure).Count; $i = $i + 1){

        if($result.CertName[$i].Contains($certNameMath)){

            $result.CertName[$i]
            $certHash = $result.CertificateHash[$i]
        }

    }
    $rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportServerWebApp","https://+:$httpsPort",(Get-Culture).Lcid)
    $rsConfig.ReserveURL("ReportServerWebService","https://+:$httpsPort",(Get-Culture).Lcid)
    $rsConfig.CreateSSLCertificateBinding('ReportServerWebApp', $certHash, $ipAddress, $httpsport, (Get-Culture).Lcid)
    $rsConfig.CreateSSLCertificateBinding('ReportServerWebService', $certHash, $ipAddress, $httpsport, (Get-Culture).Lcid) 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "already has https"
}
```

Note, the scripts varies a bit among versions of SSRS, so your mileage may vary.